# Get current screen dimensions via Xlib using C

Tags: xorg, c, programming

Is there any way to get screen dimensions of a display via Xlib using C? I've tried referring to the X.org docs (https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/display/screen-information.html), and it only gives me macros which do not accept integers, so I'm at a loss.

I specifically used these functions in this way:

```
int sx;
int sy;
XWidthOfScreen(sx);
XWidthOfScreen(sy);

...

move_window(sx / 4)
move_window(sy / 4)
```

I'm a noob to C programming, and am working on my first project.

Comment: Your program has to open the display.  Reading the source for [`xdpyinfo`](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xdpyinfo) would be a start.

Comment: I'm modding a window manager, so it does this for me. sowm to be exact. (http://github.com/dylanaraps/sowm) Should I specify this in the question?

Comment: @user396530 Yes, you'd better give more complete information in your question regarding your situation. Also, describe in more details any research you've done prior to asking this question, and what you have attempted and how those attempts failed. Otherwise, I believe, X.org and working with it through C API must be on-topic here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a simple example, which will print the display size and move the window of the terminal emulator it runs in (if correctly set in the `WINDOWID` environment variable) to width / 4, height / 4:

```c
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int ac, char **av){
        char *wid; Display *dpy; Window w;
        int width, height, snum;
        if(!(dpy = XOpenDisplay(0)))
                errx(1, "cannot open display '%s'", XDisplayName(0));
        snum = DefaultScreen(dpy);
        width = DisplayWidth(dpy, snum);
        height = DisplayHeight(dpy, snum);
        printf("display size is %d x %d\n", width, height);
        if((wid = getenv("WINDOWID")) && (w = strtoul(wid, 0, 0))){
                XMoveWindow(dpy, w, width / 4, height / 4);
                XSync(dpy, False);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

My advice would be a copy of [The X11 Programming Manual](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/libX11/libX11/libX11.html), which is a single page html which you can search through and contains everything about X11 programming.

Notice that there may be more friendly or portable libraries, like gtk, qt, sdl, etc. You may want to use one of those instead of libX11 directy.

Comment: Just another quick question: how do you obtain ```dpy``` programmatically?

Comment: Via `XOpenDisplay`, as in my example ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your helpful code sample and recommendation. :D